# Set multiple variables in httpd conf

Tags: php, apache-2.4, httpd

I have the following httpd configuration

```
 <Directory "..">
        AllowOverride All
      SetEnv ENV local
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I'd like to add more variable like ENV
for example  ,  URL_PATH = "c:/programs_files" 
is it possible to use it here? if yes , how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple `SetEnv` directives.